# How to rewrite php files in specific folders

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem on rewriting couple of files in `.htaccess`.

**My concept:**  In my site im allowing people to create a profile on their own name.

Its like `www.site.com/username`. If they access this URL, they can grab the details according to the user name . In a example if i access this URL `www.site.com/mark` then I can view his all details.

What I'm doing is that I'm creating a folder upon the profile creating process and I'm copying all the default php files in to that created folder.
I have stored my php files such as Index.php, about.php, settings.php in a separate folder and I'm copying these php file in to the folder which is created on the process.

So, if a user access this URL `www.site.com/mark/about.php`, Then that user can get details about mark.

But what I want is to look that URL like this `www.site.com/mark/about`.

When I trying to rewrite this URL, I faced a big problem. Which is that I don't really know which username they are going to be use as their URL.

In a example someone might use `www.site.com/alex`,  "`www.site.com/sheryl`

There for I don't know how to write this URL.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule, put this in root directory of project.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ $1/$2.php [L]
```

here you can use any name and file which is present will shown to the user.